# Dynamic Screen size in Qt for Nokia

Tags: qt

How to Make Dynamic Screen of  different size in QT for Nokia Devices in QT Creator?

Answer (score 0):

Just [set](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setWindowState) fullscreen window state on your topmost widget:

```
w->setWindowState(w->windowState() ^ Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

The fullscreen window fills the entire screen without any frame around it.

Answer (score 0):

do it in this way it works fine:

```
MyMainWindow::QMyMainWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags) : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

QFrame* frame = new QFrame(this);
setCentralWidget(frame);

frame->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

QRect rect(0, 0, 240, 320);
frame->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
frame->setLineWidth(3);
frame->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Plain);
frame->setGeometry(rect);

adjustSize();
}
```

I didn't specify main window size at first and it would be totally expanded by central widget.
I also tried other SizePolicy values, but the resulting size of main window was not (240, 320) as expected at all.